# Google+ API json out of chronological order

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-plus

On my website, I have javascript that accesses my posts on Google+ and prints out the latest 10. The json file that I get from Google+ is coming out of chronological order and doesn't include the latest posts (at least in the "most recent" 10 that I show). My website appears to be working fine as it shows the same info that the json file does. I just reset the public key to see if that helped and it is still the same. It worked fine until recently.

http://coinimaging.com

Answer (score 0):

In this api document it shows that you can pass "orderby": https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search?hl=no

You could try to call google+ with this parameter in your ajax call (I couldn't tests
because I couldn't reproduce/understand your issues exactly) - see "&orderBy=recent" at
end of URI: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/109969197725030160627/activities/public?key=AIzaSyAqi0pREowegFz4P-8_653BEp_NsOdcsik&orderBy=recent